# QGIS Random Points Inside Polygons Based on Attbribute Value?

Tags: qgis

How can I set Random Points Inside Polygons so that the number of points created inside each feature is based on an attribute value for that feature?

Based on other answers I see elsewhere on Stack Exchange, there should be an option for this in the GUI but I'm not seeing it.
[image]

I'm using QGIS version 3.10.6 (A Coruña).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use an attribute to determinate the number of points inside each polygon you need to use the Data Defined Override in the option *Point count or density*
Here you can use an expression or just add a field from the attribute table using `"FIELD_NAME"` as syntax.

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thank you.